# How to render from Mapnik at a specific scale?

Tags: mapnik

I'm trying to render a map to paper using Mapnik at a specific scale (such as 1:50k), but can't yet figure out how. So far I'm just using `map.zoom_to_box`:

```
map.zoom_to_box (mapnik.Envelope (101.5,3.2,102,3.3))
```

and play with `MaxScaleDenominator` and `MinScaleDenominator` in the styling rules..

But when done this way, I can only guess-work the map scale by adjusting the bounding box over and over, which is hard to obtain the exact 1:50k scale that I wanted.. I've also found this: `map.scale_denominator()` and `map.scale()`, but I think these are used only to display the map scale - not setting it..

Is there anyone here who can help me?

Comment: Hi Haziq, welcome to the forums. I'm not a Mapnik user so I haven't tested this, but [here's a post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/openlayers-use-scales-instead-of-resolutions) regarding the same issue in OpenLayers, which might also be applicable?

Comment: Interesting syntax usages.. Don't know whether they'll work with Mapnik or not, so I'll try them on. Thanks @StephenLead!

Comment: @StephenLead My python's a little rusty, so I can't get those to work with Mapnik..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround to my problem, but it's not a neat one.
Basically:

1. I used `print map.scale_denominator()` to figure out the scale of my current selection bounding box
2. `map.pan_and_zoom(+x,+y,z)` to pan and zoom to the area that I wanted
3. Used `print map.envelope()`. This will give out the current bounding box used after panning: `Box2d(minlong,minlat,maxlong,maxlat)`
4. Adjust `map.pan_and_zoom(+x,+y,z)` z-values to zoom until `map.scale_denominator()` printout the scale value I wanted (50k)
5. When the map is panned at the right location, I just read the current `map.envelope()` values and transfer them into the `map.zoom_to_box` as the new bounding box. I'll comment out `map.pan_and_zoom(+x,+y,z)` when I'm done.

The overall code will look something like this:

```
map = mapnik.Map (3000, 3000)
mapnik.load_map (map, "mapDefinition.xml")
map.zoom_to_box (mapnik.Envelope (101.789315885,3.1540902527,101.977962094,3.3427364622))
map.pan_and_zoom(+1000,-100,0.568)
mapnik.render_to_file (map,"map.png")
print map.scale_denominator(), map.scale()
print map.envelope()
```

Like I said - messy. But it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks for this. This "guessing" process can be easily automated, but it's a _huge_ hack. Is there really no better way?!

Comment: There should be (still waiting for a better answer). I haven't been using Mapnik for a while, and I've long stopped researching for a better answer. Maybe you should take a look at TileMill or Mapbox Studio, and see how they do it.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.britishideas.com/2009/09/22/map-scales-and-printing-with-mapnik/) should answer your question. Basically you should do a bit of math based on the resolution at which you want to print.

Comment: I've already delved into this blog post: that's where I got the idea on how to get the exact numbers for the scale. The problem is I don't where to plug-in that calculated `scale-denominater` value.. Thx for trying @gomatteo !